# Telecash IPG Connect issues

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I am integrating FirstData Telecash IPG Connect, 
i configured it the same way mentioned in the document(http://www.telecash.de/fileadmin/data/IPG/IPG_IntegrationGuide_Connect_2_9.pdf),

but still get the same issue again and again that your "Pyament was not successfull"..

Did anybody worked on that??
 Please share your experience.

Thank you

Comment: Right...even though I most likely can't help, others may be able to, if you just showed us what code you actually tried. Don't just link to the tutorial, in 9 of 10 cases it's a typo in the implementation.

Comment: The code is mentioned there in the tutorial, i just used that..nothing different

Comment: you can take the PHP example..in the tutorial.

Comment: So you're saying it's exactly the same code? Even the credentials for authentication are exactly the same? Letter by letter? And you've used an even amount of money for your testcase, correct?

Comment: yes everything is same except that i am not using testing credetials, i am using live credentials..including the post url, store Id etc

Comment: Have you tried the example with the testing credentials then? Just to make sure, that the code is, indeed, working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the problem has been solved, 
the problem is in telecash documentation, they did not mentioned in the document that the response URLs are mandatory..
So without added the response you can not successfully integrate the connect..

After adding the response URL it worked for me..